# How to run timer for each user on server

Tags: c#, server

Im working on simple game server which is supposed to work like this:

1. user connect to server and start timer, setting variable Quest to true
2. the timer will count down X seconds
3. user can disconnect from the server, and connect again from same or different device to check the timer progress (if variable Quest == true, the quest is in progress)
4. when the timer reach 0, it will set Quest to false

the server is supposed to handle multiple users at the same time.

my problem: ive already done part 1 and 2, but i dont have any clue how to connect variable to some username. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: When the user disconnects, you need to store the time with their username somewhere, e.g. in a database. Then when they reconnect with the same username, you can fetch the value from the storage by searching using that username. Obviously if the variable has been static in that time, you'll need to calculate the time elapsed since the value was stored, and update it before giving it to the user. So when you first store it, it would be sensible to also store the time at that moment

Comment: Don't use a timer. Set an deadline for the quest, e.g. if you would have used a one-hour timer, set the deadline to `DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)`. Then it won't matter if they're logged in or logged off and you don't have to maintain the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you currently have something like:

```
class GameServer {
    Timer questTimer;
    bool quest;
    // ...
```

then you might want to encapsulate that global state into a class of its own for each player:

```
class PlayerState {
    Timer questTimer;
    bool quest;
}
```

and have a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) keyed by the player's name for each player's state:

```
class GameServer {
    Dictionary<string, PlayerState> states = new Dictionary<string, PlayerState>();
    // ...
```

Manipulating Dictionaries is beyond the scope of this question – the article linked above should give you some ideas.

Comment: Wait..... i cant believe that i COMPLETELY forgot about dictionaries xd.
This answer should do the trick, sorry for dumb question :D